# Редирект .htaccess убрать / с конца ссылки

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
Как сделать редирект при переходе по site.com/news/ на site.com/news?
Живой пример: formulaz.ru/mrt-skani/ нужно переадресовать на http://formulaz.ru/mrt-skani
И еще, возможно ли сделать ридирект с site.com/error/news/ на site.com/news,  словом принцип такой:
site.com/../../news на site.com/news. пример - formulaz.ru/sometext/mrt-skani - страница отображается но хотелось бы еще сделать переадресацию на http://formulaz.ru/mrt-skani

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Этот вариант не работает,  потому, что в файле апача уже есть такой код:

```
#php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off
Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?module=search&mode=text&page=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?module=search&mode=text&page=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^news$ index.php?module=news&page=news [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ index.php?module=news&post=$1&page=news [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^reviews$ index.php?module=ot&page=ot [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)$ index.php?module=ot&post=$1&page=ot [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?module=static_content&page=$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Срочно надо, буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь со знающих поможет!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Покажите в вопросе, как вы эти два файла соединили.